# Mute Rails memcache logging in development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, memcached, environment, dalli

Would like to mute large amount of dalli output in development log & STOUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an initialiser with the following:

```
Rails.cache.silence!
```

Taken from https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/207